# Google calendar synced to Outlook can't add or modify events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar, microsoft-outlook-2019

I followed [these instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126) for importing my Google Calendar into Outlook 2019 as an "Internet Calendar". The calendar now shows up in Outlook under "My Calendars", and if I accept a meeting request from an Outlook email then the meeting gets added as an event in the Outlook calendar. However, if I try to manually add my own event to the calendar, it errors saying that it's read-only:

[image: Error #1 screenshot]

Similarly, if I edit an existing event (added from an email meeting request) and try to change anything such as setting a reminder, it gives another error about reminders not being supported and asking if it's OK (it's not OK...)

[image: Error #2 screenshot]

What do I need to do to get my Google Calendar syncing properly with Outlook, so that I can add and make changes to events?

Comment: It is not (yet) possible to edit Google Calendar from Outlook (!!). This is absurd for such an expensive professional program, but unfortunately it is so. I have Outlook 2021 and it is still the same. It is a pity that Microsoft never implemented such an important function in the Office suite.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the article, the imported calendar is a static snapshot.

If you subscribe to it, to update your Google calendar, we need to open Google Calendar from a browser.

Do you use Exchange account in Outlook? As far as I know, Exchange account will sync calendar items as well as emails or contacts with server. If yes, you can import Google Calendar to your existing account in Outlook client and then directly use your new calendar as a replacement.

You can refer to this thread discussed in Technet forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/19b69f07-f640-4b19-92b9-da86d1bf2a85/syncing-google-calendar-with-microsoft-outlook?forum=outlook

Comment: You say "if you subscribe to it, you can edit this calendar" however as I described, I can't add or edit events so that's not holding true in my case... We don't use Exchange, we use Google for our work mail and calendar. And I can't just import in my google calendar and use it in a silo, because then I won't have access to the same calendar on my other computers and mobile devices.

Comment: My mistake. It's not possible to edit an Internet calendar in Outlook client. You can update your Google calendar from browser if you don't want to switch to Exchange account.
Besides, have you checked the link above? We use a utility to sync the calendar if you needed to edit it: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/sync-outlook/sync-google-calendar-outlook/#tools